# Django After login succeed, redirect again to login page

Tags: python, django

My Django project has 5 apps: app1, app2 ......
each app has one template index.html and 1 view named index.
project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

app1/urls.py

```
 from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from . import views
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
```

app1/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
def is_member(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='group1').exists()

@login_required
@user_passes_test(is_member)
def index(request):
    getting our template
    template = loader.get_template('app1/index.html')
    rendering the template in HttpResponse
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

setting.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

The 5 apps requirer login based on group 
app one I have no problem to login but the reset of the apps after login succeed, I will be redirected to login page again.
The reset of the apps has exactly the same code except the group name and template location.
Also  the logger result show me that there is no problem with credential.

I tried to change the group nae for other app as app1 and still I am getting same result.

Please advice me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you saying that `/` is redirected to `/accounts/login/`?

Comment: yes login page it will reload again

Comment: Have you checked that your `is_member` function is returning `True`? It will redirect to the login page if it returns False. Alternatively, try comment that decorator out to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? Do you want it to reload to a different page?

Comment: I commented is_member() and it works but all user now can login. and I tested is_member() and it passes False and I am sure of the user name and the password and group name